# Mock dependency with ApplicationContextRunner in SpringBoot Test result into UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have following class, which publishes the spring event.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationReadyEventListener {
    Boolean isHit = false;

    @EventListener
    public void handle(final ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {

applicationReadyEvent.getSpringApplication().getClass().toGenericString()));
        isHit = true;                              // This needs to be replaced with CustomLoggerComponent
    }
}
```

As I need to publish the event and need to check failure and success event, I have following test:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
class ApplicationReadyEventListenerTest {


    private final ApplicationContextRunner runner = new ApplicationContextRunner();


//Success Test 
@Test
    void loggerShouldLogWhenApplicationIsReady() {
        SpringApplciation application = new SpringApplication(ApplicationReadyEventListener.class);

        application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        final ApplicationReadyEvent event = new ApplicationReadyEvent(application, null, mock(ConfigurableApplicationContext.class));
        runner.withBean(ApplicationReadyEventListener.class)
              .run(context -> {
                  context.publishEvent(event);

                  final ApplicationReadyEventListener applicationStartedListener = context.getBean(ApplicationReadyEventListener.class);
                  MatcherAssert.assertThat(applicationStartedListener.isHit(), is(true));
              });
    }

//FailureTest 
    @Test
    void shouldNotCallApplicationStarted() {
 SpringApplciation application = new SpringApplication(ApplicationReadyEventListener.class);
        application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);

        final RuntimeException runtimeException = new RuntimeException("Some Error Occurred");
        final ApplicationEvent event            = new ApplicationFailedEvent(application, null, mock(ConfigurableApplicationContext.class), runtimeException);

        runner.withBean(ApplicationReadyEventListener.class)
              .run(context -> {
                  context.publishEvent(event);

                  final ApplicationReadyEventListener applicationStartedListener = context.getBean(ApplicationReadyEventListener.class);
                  MatcherAssert.assertThat(applicationStartedListener.isHit(), is(false));
              });
    }

}
```

This is working fine as of now as the class (ApplicationReadyEventListener) does not have any bean. I want to have a custom logger for this one, and instead of isHit, I would be checking the side effect of custom logger's method getting called.

However, I could not add any dependency, so I tried to isolate the problem by creating a separate application which contains the subject under test `ApplicationReadyEvent` and to have CustomLoggerBean created, used following one:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomLogMockProvider {

    @Bean
    public  Logger logger() {
        return Mockito.mock(Logger.class);
    }
}
```

And when I write this test for the same:

```
   @Test
    void tesCustomLoggerBeanPresence() {
        SpringApplciation application = new SpringApplication(CustomLogger.class);

        application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);

        runner.withBean(CustomLogMockProvider.class)
                .run(context -> {

                    String[] beanNamesForType = context.getBeanNamesForType(Logger.class);
            Arrays.stream(beanNamesForType).forEach(System.out::println); 
        });
    }
```

Getting `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` for the above one.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationReadyEventListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [java.lang.Class] to required type [com.priti.com.common.config.CustomLogger]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.Class' to required type 'com.priti.com.common.config.CustomLogger'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Class' to required type 'com.priti.com.common.config.CustomLogger': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Any lead on this would be helpful.

Comment: Under what package do you have this CustomLogMockProvider  class ?

Comment: the subject under test, its corresponding test, and the CustomLogMockProvider are in the same package.

Comment: How are you injecting the CustomLogger component into your ApplicationReadyEventListener component?

Comment: I have created a `CustomMockProviderMock` and starting the application with that. Given that's there, `CustomLogger` would be available as bean and thus should be able to Autowire. 
Given this is the logic, I did check on presence of bean for `CustomLogger` by starting application only with `CustomLogProvider` and I could find it. 

Given both bean are present, if I start them together, it should be able to autowire, but getting following exception: 

`
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Class' to required type
`

Answer (score 1):

I think your test setup is the problem. You're doing far to much things by hand instead of using the proper Spring tooling.

If you want to test your `ApplicationReadyEventListener` the test should look like this:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationReadyEventListener.class)
class ApplicationReadyEventListenerTest {

    @MockBean
    private SpringApplication springApplicationMock;

    @MockBean
    private CustomLogger customLoggerMock;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Test
    void name() {
        publisher.publishEvent(new ApplicationReadyEvent(springApplicationMock, null, null));
        verify(customLoggerMock).doSomething();
    }
}
```

You run a Spring test by using `SpringExtension.class`. You mock your `CustomLogger` as well as the `SpringApplication`. Now you can publish a `ApplicationReadyEvent` and verify that your listener has invoked the `CustomLogger`.